# How can I provide Jasper Forest CPU in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a Linux kernel source 3.4.28 and wanted to know is there any way to tune this kernel to support Intel's Jasper Forest CPU.

Is there any configuration file where I can tweak Jasper Forest CPU support and compiled kernel can up Jasper Forest CPU on board.

Comment: I guess it probably might work on recent vanilla 3.7 or 3.8 kernels from http://kernel.org/

Comment: Thanks Basile for your response but would like to know is there any config file needs to be updated in order to support  Jasper Forest CPU

Comment: I don't really know, but I don't think so.

Comment: Is there something that is not working for you? As far as I can tell your kernel version should support that CPU reasonably well - linux-3.4 was released almost two years after that processor...

Comment: Well @thkala we are trying to up the board which have Japer Forest Cpu ,our bootloader is able to put the linux kernel image to specified entry point in memory but soon after its asserting reset single to CPU, don't know why.So we thought it could be Kernel image issue.Basically just not able to boot with Linux Image and since we are new to board bring up stuff facing trouble to boot the board.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: so you are using an embedded board... *Which* board is that?

Comment: Yes, Its Intel jasper forest 4 board customized a bit.

Comment: Just to inform you we have compiled our kernel with Core 2/newer Xeon processor family.